# Adding a resizeFilter makes image vanish

Tags: fabricjs

I've created a `FabricJS` canvas and added an image with a `resizeFilter`. Strangely, the image disappears when you scale the image size down just a bit. When no `resizeFilter` is added to the image then resizing works as expected.

Thanks for the help!

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var imageSrc = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabricjs.com/gh-pages/assets/pug.jpg";

fabric.Image.fromURL(imageSrc, function(img) {
  img.set({
    left: 10,
    scaleX: 0.52,
    scaleY: 0.52,
    top: 10,
  }, {
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });

  img.resizeFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
    resizeType: 'lanczos'
  });
  img.applyResizeFilters();

  canvas.add(img);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
1. Resize the image to make it smaller<br>
2. When it gets a bit smaller, the image disappears
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" class="c"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting cross origin issue, apply `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` to image object while loading using `fabric.Image.fromURL`.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var imageSrc = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabricjs/fabricjs.com/gh-pages/assets/pug.jpg";

fabric.Image.fromURL(imageSrc, function(img) {
  img.set({
    left: 10,
    scaleX: 0.52,
    scaleY: 0.52,
    top: 10
  });
  img.resizeFilter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize({
    resizeType: 'lanczos'
  });
  img.applyResizeFilters();
  canvas.add(img);
}, {
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks Durga, I see from your snippet that I was simply applying the `resizeFilter` in the wrong place.